# Expand and Collapse

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to expand and collapse.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1');" >Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>

<div id="id1">This is foo</div>


<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id2');" >Click here to see wonder</a>

<div id="id2">This is foo</div>
```

I want +(plus) image when collapse and -(minus) image when expand.
Please help me with code to do that.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Where you want to put those images? To the `a`s?

Comment: Use assignment to `.innerHTML` to change the content of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it using jquery? Please visit this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XEz7/)

Js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#toggle-view li').click(function () {

        var text = $(this).children('div.panel');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('-');     
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('+');     
        }

    });

});
```